# cPanel's cron job creates aliases of PHP file for unknown reason...?

Tags: php, cron, duplicates, alias, cpanel

I have cron jobs setup that runs a few PHP scripts often. The issue is that each time it runs a script, it create an alias of it, or an empty file with the same filename and a number added at the end.

For instance, one of the files are activesessions_update.cron.php, here is the script inside it:

```
<?php
  $memcache = new Memcache; 
  $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);
  $activeSessions = $memcache->getStats(); 

  // using heredoc
$file_content = <<<TEXT
<?php

\$activeSessions = {$activeSessions['curr_items']};

?>
TEXT;

// this would be a user-defined function
file_put_contents("activesessions.php", $file_content);
?>
```

In my route folder, this is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3kp8.png

In cPanel, the cron job runs the command:

```
/usr/bin/wget http://domain.com/x/activesessions_update.cron.php
```

I have no idea what the problem is. I am forced to delete 10,000s of these empty files every week. Please note that **I have no experience in PHP programming** as I did not code it myself so any replies would be appreciated with utter detail. Who can guide me to solve this puzzle?

EDIT: Got the solution from techincal support of my host:

> It wasn't logging exactly, by default wget is used to download files. 
>   So when you run wget against that url it goes out, requests the file,
>   and downloads the output of the request, essentially saving a copy of
>   what you would get in your browser if you pulled it up.  By adding the
>   -O /dev/null to the command you are telling it that instead of saving
>   that output to the default location (generally wherever it was being
>   called from) to save it to /dev/null which is really just nowhere
>   (basically just throws it away)

Comment: You seem to have (at least) two servers involved here - the one the cron job is scheduled on, and the one that the script is executed on - unless you are calling back to your own server. Which one are the duplicate files being created on? And also, the comment that says `this would be a user-defined function` - is that exactly what is in the file, or is it a user defined function that you have substituted with `file_put_contents()` for the purpose of this post?

Comment: you can try adding `> /dev/null` to the end of the cron command to avoid the log output.

Comment: @Daverandom I am calling back to my own server. Note that all of the files that are cron jobed create this type of file.

Comment: @ldg could you please elaborate on that. Would I add it like this: /usr/bin/wget http://domain.com/x/activesessions_update.cron.php /dev/null?

Comment: It must be said this is an odd way to go about this job. You are calling a local script via HTTP, which adds something of a processing overhead, and means that errors will be quite hard to catch. It would be far better to change the command that is invoked to `php /actual/local/path/to/activesessions_update.cron.php`

Comment: `/usr/bin/wget domain.com/x/activesessions_update.cron.php > /dev/null`

Comment: @DaveRandom sorry do you mind explaining this further? If I changed it to what you suggest, will it display errors? Or did I misunderstand this?

Comment: @Johan What ldg is suggesting is sensible - the best way to do it would be to change your cron job to this: `/usr/bin/wget domain.com/x/activesessions_update.cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @ldg you need to add `2>&1` to catch STDERR as well

Comment: @DaveRandom your suggesting is different to ldg. You are adding "2>&1", what does that do in more detail?

Comment: @Johan What it means is that it would get errors throw by PHP, rather than errors thrown by wget, which is what you will get at the moment.

Comment: @Johan you are redirecting STDOUT and STDERR to /dev/null. If you don't add the `2>&1` you wont get the stuff written to STDERR, you'll only get whats written to STDOUT. This would (probably, if this is the problem) result in the files still being created. I have my doubts as to whether this is the problem though, as I would have thought the files would have a .log extension if they were log files...

Comment: @Dave I did what you suggested below and opened the alias file and it contained this: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  This is a test error in <b>/home/USER/public_html/activesessions_update.cron.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />

Comment: Right, it looks like they are log files then. Try the output redirection as suggested by @ldg (use the version with `2>&1` in it though), and if that doesn't work I have a cunning plan... (and you can remove that line again now, was just to test whether you would get any output)

Comment: Very well, give me a moment to adjust the cron job, and see how it outputs. Please stay here.

Comment: It did not work. There was still files created. Although I did not restart apache or anything similar if that is needed after changing a cron job command...?

Comment: shouldn't be, as the file will be being created by cron itself (or more to the point, the way it is configured). It's an ugly work-around, but you should be able to just have the PHP script delete the log files. You will still have 1 or 2 files floating around, but at least it will be tidier. I'll post an answer in a few minutes, it's too much to put in a comment.

Comment: Thank you, I look forward to that answer reply. Do you have any idea why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have established that these are log files created by cron, a work-around is to have the PHP script delete the log files as it is run. Change `activesessions_update.cron.php` to this - **back up the original version in a different directory first!**

I am assuming that the files are created in such a way that the user you script is run as has permissions to delete the files. If it is not, this wont work.

```
<?php

  $memcache = new Memcache; 
  $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);
  $activeSessions = $memcache->getStats(); 

  // Removed slightly pointless heredoc
  $file_content = "<?php\n\n\  $activeSessions = {$activeSessions['curr_items']};\n\n?>";

  // this would be a user-defined function
  // What does the above comment mean? Are you supposed
  // to replace this with some of your own code?
  file_put_contents("activesessions.php", $file_content);


  // ========================================================
  //     Everything below here is to delete old log files


  // Change this to the directory where the log files end up
  $logsdir = "/home/USER/";

  // Get the name of this file and length of the name
  $filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  $namelength = strlen($filename);

  // Strip any trailing slashes from $logsdir
  $logsdir = rtrim($logsdir,'/\\');

  // Open the logs directory
  if (!$dp = opendir($logsdir)) {
    trigger_error("Could not open logs directory '$logsdir' for reading, exiting...");
    exit;
  }

  // Loop through the files in the directory
  while ($file = readdir($dp)) {
    if (!in_array($file,array('.','..',$filename)) && strlen($file) > $namelength && substr($file,0,$namelength) == $filename) {
      // If the start of the file name is the same as this file,
      // and the file name length is longer than the length of the
      // name of this file, delete it.
      @unlink("$logsdir/$file");
    }
  }

  // Close the directory pointer
  @closedir($dp);

?>
```

I guess the cron daemon on your server is configured to redirect STDOUT and STDERR of all the cron jobs it runs to a file. It seems odd that it is configured like this, as it will cause problems like you are having. Also, it seems very odd that it should redirect them to files that have, essentially, the same name of your script with a number on the end. You would have though they would be `*.log` or something.

This solution will still leave at least one log file in existence at any one time, because you definitely wont be able to delete the file that is currently being written to.

If this does work, you can safely copy/paste the same code (from below the `=====` comment line) into any other files that are called by cron jobs and are causing the same problem, as long as they are:

- creating the log files in the same directory that the script resides
- the only file in the directory (that you actually want) where the file name starts with the full name of the script file

Comment: Do I add the new lines to the other php files that the cron job runs? I will test this now and report back within a few minutes...

Comment: If there are permission issues, another cron could be setup to remove the files, perhaps on a less frequent basis.

Comment: @Johan yes you should be able to add this to whichever files you want, as long as they meet a couple of conditions (see the note at the bottom of my edited answer)

Comment: It did not work. Just saw another of these log files. Although I should note that log files end up in directory: /home/USER/ while the php file is in: /home/USER/public_html/x/activesessions_update.cron.php I don't know if that changes anything but thought I should make a note of it...

Comment: @Jared that is a sensible suggestion - would you have to create an shell script or can you call a `for` loop directly from crond?

Comment: @johan yes that does make a difference, I will modify the above code. Note that you will always have at least one file there, because you can't delete the one that is being written to (i.e. the one for the current process)

Comment: @Johan edited the above code, try again...  (and don't forget to set the directory name as appropriate)

Comment: Okay I added the new code and adjusted the user but still didn't work. In the root folder this file activesessions_update.cron.php and this file activesessions_update.cron.php.1 exists. Any solutions?

Comment: Great news, it appears that it will not create the third file (yay)! This is a rather bizarre solution to this problem but I guess it will due for now. Before I give you a mental appreciation for your assistance, is there any way to have the $logsdir = "/home/USER/"; to not contain the direct path of the server? The reason for this is that incase I move servers and the path/folders are changed, I will need to adjust these files accordingly. Or another solution would be to have a standalone php script that runs this command and deletes all logs and I will only need to adjust that one then...?

Comment: To be honest, if you move server you hopefully wont have this problem. It's worth contacting your host to see if they can help you stop the files being created in the first place. If you have disabled logging in cPanel, I would say this shouldn't be happening at all. It could be transferred to a single script that deletes all the log files (this is what @Jared suggested above) but the rules to determine which files to delete and which to leave would be more complicated. To set this up I would need a complete list of all the scripts that create the files.

Comment: If I rememeber correctly, I did disable logging when I setup my server. Do you happen to know how to disable it as it was over a year ago that I was playing with the backend...?

Comment: Also, if I move server and the new server doesn't log. What happens with this new code added? Will I need to remove it or will it not cause any particular damage?

Comment: Is it a full WHM-based box? How much control do you have over it? Is it your own WHM/cPanel based box, reseller account, etc etc and what version are you running? And to be fair, the answer is probably 'no' because I have only ever really used the front end of WHM and cPanel. I woud guess that is some kind of config file that can only be accessed by the owner of the box, certainly not through any account that is chrooted like all the web users should/would be.

Comment: Techical support for my server said this just now: Right, I believe you are getting the files as wget is actually downloading the file you are pointing it at.  If you are simply using wget to do a call to the script through the webserver and not to actually try and download anything you might try "wget -O /dev/null http://www.the-artifice.com/x/activesessions_update.cron.php"

Comment: Right, that makes sense. That explains the file names as well. What I would actually recommend you do instead, as it will reduce overhead, is change it to `php /home/USER/public_html/x/activesessions_update.cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1` - this means you are invoking the script locally and not getting the web server involved in the process. It would involve changing the original script slightly to ensure that the "activesessions.php" file that it creates/updates ends up in the right place. It's up to you - their solution will work but it's not the best way of doing it...

Comment: I will edit my question with this solution, although I will keep your answer as the correct answer because it was definitely helpful and correct although it choose a different path. Thank you very much for the assistance buddy!

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that these are log files containing the output of the script, created by cPanel's *cron*. Check you cPanel's configuration and disable logging if you don't need it.

Comment: I already have logging disabled in cPanel so no it is not log files. All of the files are empty inside...

Comment: @Johan Try adding this line (on a line on it's own) to the `activesessions_update.cron.php` file, immediately after `<?php` and before the next line: `trigger_error('This is a test error');` and then check the next file that is created, to see if it contains the text `This is a test error`